# Manually constructing a Dynamic Link URL with OFL Parameter not working on Desktop Browser

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I created dynamic link **(React-Native App)** which is working perfectly on Android & iOS devices but if open same link on desktop browser it say "Dynamic link not found/Invalid dynamic link". I have created custom dynamic link as well as using Firebase dynamic link

**--- Using Firebase Link ---**

```
await firebase.dynamicLinks().buildShortLink(
    {
      domainUriPrefix: `${prefix_url}`,
      link: `${prefix_url}/${params}`,
      android: {
        packageName: `${package_name}`,
      },
      ios: {
        bundleId: `${bundle_id}`,
        appStoreId: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
      },
      otherPlatform: {
        fallbackUrl: `${web_url}`,
      },
    },
    firebase.dynamicLinks.ShortLinkType.UNGUESSABLE,
  );
```

**--- By Custom Link ---**

```
longDynamicLink: `${prefix_url}/?link=${link_url}&apn=${package_name}&ibi=${bundle_id}&isi=xxxxxxxxx&ofl=${web_url}`,

    suffix: {
      option: 'UNGUESSABLE',
    },
  };
```

**Issue -: Link on desktop browser not working (fallback url not working)**

Dynamic link should redirect a website link on desktop